# Access class functions in unmanaged c++ dll from c# project

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I have an unmanaged (it has be unmanaged for some reasons) c++ dll (written by myself) and I'd like to access a functions of a class from that dll. What is the simpliest way to do this ? (May be without writing managed c++ wrapper).
The structure of the dll: 
It has two classes. One inhereted from other and in this inhereted class there are some overloaded functions(my target). 
I could not declare this functions in dll as

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

but my class is `__declspec(dllexport)`
Maybe there is some way to use Interopability from c# to get access to this class?

Comment: You can only pinvoke static functions, not C++ class instance methods.  You have to write a C++/CLI wrapper for those.  Or expose them through COM.